# Prolog: define logical operator in Prolog as placeholder for other operator

Tags: prolog, operator-keyword, placeholder

my aim is to write a little prove assistant in prolog. My first step is to define the logical connectives as follows:

```
:-op(800, fx, -).

:-op(801, xfy, &).

:-op(802, xfy, v).

:-op(803, xfy, ->).

:-op(804, xfy, <->).

:-op(800, xfy, #).
```

The last operator # just has the meaning to be the placeholder for `&`, `v`, `->` or `<->`. My problem is, I don't know how I it is possible to define this in prolog. I tried to solve my problem in the following way:

```
X # Y :- X v Y; X & Y; X -> Y; X <-> Y.
```

but the following definition:

```
proposition(X) :- atomicproposition(X).

proposition(X # Y) :- proposition(X), proposition(Y).

proposition(- X) :- proposition(X).
```

with

```
atomicproposition(a).
```

gives

```
?- proposition(a v -a).
false
```

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define syntactic synonyms this way. When you define something like

```
X # Y :-
    X & Y.
```

you define *semantics*: "to execute `X # Y`, execute `X & Y`". But you haven't defined any way to "execute `X & Y`":

```
?- X # Y.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (&)/2
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _2406&_2408
ERROR:    [8] _2432#_2434 at /home/isabelle/op.pl:13
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

(And even if you had defined some meaning for it, it might not be what you want.)

What you are looking for instead is a way to define a notion of not only "`T` is a term with a binary operator", but ideally also "`T`'s operands are `X` and `Y`". Like this:

```
binary_x_y(X  v  Y, X, Y).
binary_x_y(X  &  Y, X, Y).
binary_x_y(X  -> Y, X, Y).
binary_x_y(X <-> Y, X, Y).
```

And then, with:

```
proposition(X) :-
    atomicproposition(X).
proposition(Binary) :-
    binary_x_y(Binary, X, Y),
    proposition(X),
    proposition(Y).
proposition(- X) :-
    proposition(X).

atomicproposition(a).
```

We get:

```
?- proposition(a v -a).
true ;
false.

?- proposition(P).
P = a ;
P =  (a v a) ;
P =  (a v a v a) ;
P =  (a v a v a v a) ;
P =  (a v a v a v a v a) ;
P =  (a v a v a v a v a v a) .  % unfair enumeration
```

There are other ways of expressing the same relation with a bit less typing, for example:

```
binary_x_y(Binary, X, Y) :-
    Binary =.. [Op, X, Y],  % Binary is of the form Op(X, Y)
    member(Op, [v, &, ->, <->]).
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer to mark the question as resolved. Thanks!