# Python: pyswip output returns Atom and Functor

Tags: python, prolog, logic, intersection

Based on some older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890053/prolog-define-logical-operator-in-prolog-as-placeholder-for-other-operator), I have some prolog program, which specifies propositions. Let's call it "logic.pl"

```
:-op(800, fx, ¬).
:-op(801, xfy, ∧).
:-op(802, xfy, ∨).
:-op(803, xfy, →).
:-op(804, xfy, ↔).
:-op(800, xfy, #).


m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X ∨ Y, X, Y).
m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X ∧ Y, X, Y).
m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X → Y, X, Y).
m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(X ↔ Y, X, Y).

m_Proposition(X) :-
    m_Proposition_Atom(X).
m_Proposition(Binary) :-
    m_Proposition_Binary_x_y(Binary, X, Y),
    m_Proposition(X),
    m_Proposition(Y).
m_Proposition(¬ X) :-
    m_Proposition(X).



m_Proposition_Atom(p).
m_Proposition_Atom(q).
```

my aim now is to process some prolog functions based on a python program. The library python gives for that purpose is pyswip.

My problem with this library now is the swipl function [intersection/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=intersection/3). If I run e.g. this function

```
intersection([A,(A→B)], [p, (p→q)], Aim).
```

from SWI-Prolog manually, I get the output I want:

```
A = p,
B = q,
Aim = [p, p→q].
```

but within the python code:

```
from pyswip import Prolog


prolog = Prolog()
prolog.consult("logic.pl")

for res in prolog.query("intersection([A,(A→B)], [p, (p→q)], Aim)."):
    print(res)
```

My output is:

```
{'A': 'p', 'B': 'q', 'Aim': [Atom('331781'), Functor(8343821,2,p,q)]}
```

My question now is, what is the reason for:

```
'Aim': [Atom('331781'), Functor(8343821,2,p,q)]
```

And is there a way to translate that into my expected output?

```
Aim = [p, p→q]
```

Comment: You might want to drop by the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) and search for `pyswip` but then also search for `swiplserver` and `MQI`. There is not enough room in the comments to give a better response but hopefully reading the query results will give you more food for thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply found some answer. I just installed the last stable version 0.2.10 with

```
pip install pyswip
```

In version 0.2.11 from [github-page](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip) this problem should be fixed. You can install 0.2.11 by command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/yuce/pyswip@master#egg=pyswip
```

my output is now:

```
[{'A': 'p', 'B': 'q', 'Aim': ['p', '→(p, q)']}]
```

Comment: Glad you find a solution. If you feel this is truly the answer for you, then you should accept it as the answer so that others can see it has an accepted answer. Your question pops up every few months and most users never report how they resolved their problem.